# Facebook API - doesn't return all fields for photos

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I am using the Facebook API to browse albums, choose an album and then output the photos on to my page.

I login successfully with Facebook. Accept app permissions. It outputs all albums on to a page to select from. I select an album and pass the album ID to another page where I output the photos. But the response doesn't have all photo fields, only `id` and `created_time`.

For example:

```
//load fb api   
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

//Initialise
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId      : 'XXXXXXXX',
    status     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    cookie     : true,
    version    : 'v2.4'
   });
}

//Get albums - This works fine.
FB.api( "/me/albums", function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            data = response.data;
            //Output albums...
        }
});
```

I select an album and pass it to a page where I output the photos like this:

```
FB.api(
    "/ALBUM_ID/photos",
    function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
);
```

This is where it breaks. The output in the log looks like:

```
Object {data: Array[1], paging: Object}
    data: Array[1]
        0: Object
           created_time: "2014-05-07T10:39:31+0000"
           id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

And that's it. No other fields. There are no errors in the log. I don't understand why I am only getting some data.

Comment: Can someone explain, why was this question down-voted? I just faced the same problem and it was really helpful for me. What was wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Graph API v2.4 reduces the number of fields in default responses.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/

> **Fewer default fields for faster performance:** To help improve performance on mobile network connections, we've reduced the number of fields that the API returns by default. You should now use the `?fields=field1,field2` syntax to declare all the fields you want the API to return.

In short, explicitly state which fields you require as part of your request.

Comment: That did the trick. I didn't know about these changes. Thanks for pointing it out.